# jquery append and ng-if not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

In my app with `checkbox`, I show and hide charts with `ng-if`, and drag&drop with angular-Dragula.
I use `ng-if` because, I take ID from visible div, and push ID to the array in the exact order and send to API.

When a user comes back, I get an array from API and I need to order everything like before he visited (of course, he again can move div, add new etc... )

But with `ng-if`  sort not working, if I remove ng-if everything is sort like in an array and this is what I need.

I need to use `ng-if`, because, when I take IDs of visible DIV, with ng-if I only get visible div, if I use ng-hide/ng-show I always get all IDs (visible and not visible)

I must use this without `ng-repeat`

Is there some solution to fix this? Mabey something instead of `ng-if`? Thnx

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [
    angularDragula(angular)      
]);

app.controller("appCtrl", ["$scope", "dragulaService", function($scope, dragulaService){

dragulaService.options($scope, "sixth-bag", {
         moves: function(el, container, handle) {
             return handle.className === "handle";
         }
     });
     
    $scope.addRemoveUserChart = function(checked, value) {
      //here I push and splice from array, depending on checkboxes and send to api. This code is not             necesarry for this question
     };
     
     
     //function where I sort DIV by ID's 
     $scope.arrangeGraphs = function (){
     //var sortorder = $scope.poredakGrafova;
     //this is for example
     var sortorder ="power, power1,power2".split(",")
             $.each(sortorder,function(index,value){
                 if($.inArray(value, sortorder) != null ){
                     console.log(value);
                 $('.results').append($('#'+value));
                 }
             });
             
     }
     
     
}])
```

```css
.graph {
background-color: red;
height: 200px;
}
.graph1 {
background-color: green;
height: 200px;
}
.graph2 {
background-color: blue;
height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-dragula/1.2.8/angular-dragula.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
<div class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxShowGraph" id="graph.power" 
    value="power" ng-checked="power"
        ng-model="power" ng-change="addRemoveUserChart(power, 'power')">
    <label for="power">Power</label>
    
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxShowGraph" id="graph.power1" 
    value="power1" ng-checked="power1"
        ng-model="power1" ng-change="addRemoveUserChart(power1, 'power1')">
    <label for="power1">Power1</label>
    
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxShowGraph" id="graph.power2" 
    value="power2" ng-checked="power2"
        ng-model="power2" ng-change="addRemoveUserChart(power2, 'power2')">
    <label for="powe2">Power2</label>
    
    
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 results" id="dragulaBox" dragula='"sixth-bag"'>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" id="power" ng-
     model="graphOrder" ng-if="power">
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 graph" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
         <span class="handle">⤭</span>
     </div>
     </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" id="power" ng-
     model="graphOrder" ng-if="power1">
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 graph1" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
         <span class="handle">⤭</span>
     </div>
     </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" id="power" ng-
     model="graphOrder" ng-if="power2">
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 graph2" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
         <span class="handle">⤭</span>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm really interesting why is this downvote? I would ask the person who gave the downvote to explain the problem, to know in the future

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, the condition in angular are where angular really shines but also a pain.

What I love to do, is to create a method, that will take the parameters and do the work as Boolean. This is one of the strongest features in angular in my opinion, you can use methods inside ng-if, ng-hide and ng-show:

```
  <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" id="power" ng-
     model="graphOrder" ng-if="contidionMethod()">
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 graph2" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
         <span class="handle">⤭</span>
     </div>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.contidionMethod = function(value) {
   if(value !== null && value === otherValue) {
       return true;
   } else {
      return false;
  }
}
```

Much more easier to understand, much more easy to handle.

Edit for your plunker script.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    angularDragula(angular)      
]);

app.controller("appCtrl", ["$scope", "dragulaService", function($scope, dragulaService){

dragulaService.options($scope, "sixth-bag", {
         moves: function(el, container, handle) {
             return handle.className === "handle";
         }
     });

    $scope.addRemoveUserChart = function(checked, value) {
      //here I push and splice from array, depending on checkboxes and send to api. This code is not             necesarry for this question
     };

     //function where I sort DIV by ID's 
     $scope.arrangeGraphs = function (){
     //var sortorder = $scope.poredakGrafova;
     //this is for example
     var sortorder ="power,power1,power2".split(",")
             $.each(sortorder,function(index,value){
                 if($.inArray(value, sortorder) != null ){
                     console.log(value);
                 $('.results').append($('#'+value));
                 }
             });

     }

        $scope.contidionMethodPower = function() {
   if(document.getElementById("graph.power").checked) {
       return true;
   }  else {
     return false;
   }
}


        $scope.contidionMethodPower1 = function() {
   if(document.getElementById("graph.power1").checked) {
       return true;
   }  else {
     return false;
   }
}


        $scope.contidionMethodPower2 = function() {
   if(document.getElementById("graph.power2").checked) {
       return true;
   }  else {
     return false;
   }
}


}])
```

And html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-dragula/1.2.8/angular-dragula.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
<div class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxShowGraph" id="graph.power" 
    value="power" ng-checked="power"
        ng-model="power" ng-change="addRemoveUserChart(power, 'power')">
    <label for="power">Power</label>

    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxShowGraph" id="graph.power1" 
    value="power1" ng-checked="power1"
        ng-model="power1" ng-change="addRemoveUserChart(power1, 'power1')">
    <label for="power1">Power1</label>

    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxShowGraph" id="graph.power2" 
    value="power2" ng-checked="power2"
        ng-model="power2" ng-change="addRemoveUserChart(power2, 'power2')">
    <label for="powe2">Power2</label>


   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 results" id="dragulaBox" dragula='"sixth-bag"'>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" id="power" ng-
     model="graphOrder"  ng-if="contidionMethodPower()">
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 graph" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
         <span class="handle">⤭</span>
     </div>
     </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" id="power" ng-
     model="graphOrder"  ng-if="contidionMethodPower1()">
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 graph1" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
         <span class="handle">⤭</span>
     </div>
     </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" id="power" ng-
     model="graphOrder"  ng-if="contidionMethodPower2()">
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 graph2" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
         <span class="handle">⤭</span>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have a problem with implementing this. I add ng-if="contidionMethod()" in every div. But in the controller, what is value in "$scope.contidionMethod = function(value) {...})" and what is otherValues? every div have an ID, so I need to pass that ID value, and show only DIV with checked ID and /or from an array... Can you pls implement your code in my snippet, because I don't know how to make this to work. Thnx

Comment: No you don't, value is whatever you pass inside (Be it array so value will be an array of data) and otherValue is the value you compare it to, in your case 'power2' for example.

Comment: Ok, I make like you say https://plnkr.co/edit/NeIjVP7JHhqw3ZEHAlPr?p=preview but now my div is not visible.

Comment: Oh I forget to add string :D but now, checkbox still not working

Comment: here you go :) Updated

Comment: Yap, this is nice, but this is same like on beginning. Sorting still not working